# Getting ID after inserting a record that has relation in Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, uniqueidentifier

I'm having a trouble with getting the id after inserting a new Record using PHP Doctrine Project.

In inserting a new record in a table with no parent table (no foreign key) no problem happens.
But when inserting a related record here comes the problem, that I get only the parent id which is useless in my case.

PHP code example:

```
$city = new City();
$city->name = "Baghdad";
$city->country_id = 6;
$city->save();
print_r($city->identifier());
exit;
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [country_id] => 6
)
```

Why the ID is empty!, where the row was inserted successfully!.
I need this to do more insertion that based the city.id, like another areas that has this city as a parent.

Note using the `$city->id` causes this error:
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Doctrine/Record.php on line 1151`

Database SQL Dump:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(64) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`country_id`),
  KEY `fk_city_country` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


ALTER TABLE `city`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_city_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

BTW: I'm using the `Doctrine::generateModelsFromDb()` method to generate ORM model classes.

PS: using the Doctrine version 1.2.1, mysql:innodb 5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2, and php 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.5.

Comment: You have two country tables in your db dump, city table is missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A co-worker discovered the solution.
It was because of this line of code:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`country_id`),
```

I used this:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
```

And it works correctly.

<strike>It's a MySQL issue I guess</strike>. It's not, it's bug in my tables design.

Comment: I was thinking of this too, why did you add the country_id to the primrary key in the first place? Or did Doctrine do that?

Comment: Really I'm not that good in MYSQL or Database in general, I'm better in coding. It's my mistake in designing the database in the first place. BTW: I used Mysql-workbench to design it.

Answer (score 0):

Does `print_r($city->get('id'));` hold more information?

Comment: No, It holds null, and causes this error:
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Doctrine/Record.php on line 1151
NULL`